# How to verify which region current Cosmos client is connected to?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/tutorial-global-distribution?tabs=dotnetv3%2Capi-async#net-sdk

> The current write and read endpoints are available in
> DocumentClient.WriteEndpoint and DocumentClient.ReadEndpoint
> respectively.

How to check from the `CosmosClient` instead? As giving in the example.
I assume the `DocumentClient` is outdated in V3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each operation you perform with the `CosmosClient` returns a response that contains a `Diagnostics` property. The `Diagnostics` contains a `GetContactedRegions()` method that returns the regions were involved in this operation: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/ebd1b91a26547721ef232ef597d878144889b80b/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Diagnostics/CosmosDiagnostics.cs#L83

Each operation for different [reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-sdk-availability) might contact one or more regions.